# Root class of the solution

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to build a network with all the solution classes as nodes - connected to their parents (classes using them) and children (classes they use). From there I want to get the "critical paths" from the root-class(es). By critical paths I mean the paths in the network that originates at the root(s).

I know you can set a specific project in a solution as the startup project. When the solution is built and run, what class in the startup project is the root or main class than is run first? - that would be my root class.

All projects in the solution are WPF projects.

Answer (score 1):

In a wpf project,by default, the first class that is called is the `App` class.

The class looks like this:

**App.xaml.cs**

```
 public partial class App : Application
    {
    }
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

As you can see there is `StartUpUri` in there which contains what window will show up first.

Comment: Great thank you - I see this in my other WPF projects but for some reason it was configured as mikus pointed out below.

Answer (score 0):

In general this is set for each project separately and it differs depending on the technology. It is easy accessible by Visual Studio, just go to the project configuration, there in Application tab you will see Startup Object, that can be selected from those that fit the requirements. See screenshot.

For Winforms this is persisted in the App.config as:

```
<StartupObject>OBJECT_NAME</StartupObject>
```

For WPF you will find it by default in App.xaml. However this could be customized in ApplicationDefinition section of the csproj file and other files could be potentially used. For Web or WCF it will be even more different as there is no real startup object, just default page.

As you can see there is no one simple answer; however for only WPF you should be able to get a fairly complete solution. Bear in mind that there are usually class libraries projects included as well.

[image: Project startup object]

Comment: Thank you - this is where my project startup class was set as well. Everything is working now!